# How to find $ \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{1-e^{-\theta/T}} $?

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I believe this should be $\frac{T}{\theta}$, but I am not sure how to get there. 
So far I have tried rational fractions techniques, e.g. breaking it into $1 + \dfrac{1}{e^{\theta/T}-1}$ and also trying to make L'Hopital's Rule applicable by changing the fraction to be $\dfrac{1-e^{-\theta/T}}{\left(1-e^{-\theta/T}\right)^2}$, however neither of these have yielded progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE** L'Hopital's Rule does not apply to limits of the form $1/0$.

**HINT** For small $x$, you have $e^x \approx 1 +x,$ so
$$
\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}} \approx \frac{1}{1 - (1+x)} = \frac{-1}{x}.
$$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

When $T \to + \infty$, $\frac{-\theta}{T}$ tends to zero regardless of $\theta$. So the limit is $\infty$ as the numerator is $1$ and the denominator tends to zero.

If $\theta > 0$

$$
\lim_{T \to +\infty} \frac{1}{1-e^{-\theta/T}} = \frac{1}{0^+} = +\infty
$$

and, if $\theta < 0$,

$$
\lim_{T \to +\infty} \frac{1}{1-e^{-\theta/T}} = \frac{1}{0^-} = -\infty
$$

[Edit]

If you consider $T/\theta$ instead of $\theta/T$ you still have two possibilities:

If $\theta >0$,
$$
\lim_{T\to +\infty}\frac{1}{1-e^{-T/\theta}}= \frac{1}{1-0} = 1
$$

If $\theta < 0$,
$$
\lim_{T\to +\infty}\frac{1}{1-e^{-T/\theta}}= \frac{1}{-\infty} = 0.
$$

Comment: If $\theta$ is negative then tends to $-\infty$

Comment: @dmitri sure, this is why I mentioned $\infty$ without a sign.

Comment: Find your answer a bit confusing, would opt for $\pm \infty$ instead

Comment: OK sorry, I thought you meant only the positive.

Comment: Just to specify - I am aware the limit goes to $\infty$, I want to know why it goes to $\infty$ with $\frac{T}{\theta}$

Comment: @user3737047 I don't see how we can help you, unless you explain where this limit comes from... You can compute the limit in both cases and,  without further information, there is no reason to prefer one over the other.

Comment: Where does it come from? The high temperature limit of the molecular partition function for vibration using a harmonic oscillator model. How do I know it is true? Well on the one hand I convinced myself of it simply by graphing the function, but I can also see why it works in gt6989b's answer. The point I was trying to make is that this could go to $\infty$ in many different ways (i.e. with a linear slope or an expoenential slope etc.), so I couldn't see why at high temperatures we should have this equal to $\frac{T}{\theta}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let

- $u=\theta/T\to 0$

then

$$\lim_{T \to +\infty} \frac{1}{1-e^{-\theta/T}} = \frac{1}{0^+} =\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{1}{1-e^{u}}=\lim_{u \to 0} \left(\frac1u \cdot\frac{u}{1-e^{u}}\right)$$

and recall that by standard limit

$$\frac{u}{1-e^{u}}=-\frac{1}{\frac{e^{u}-1}u}\to -1$$